# (Swift) API call is not going through first time, and on second attempt the call is made for the first tap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I an application that suppose to get weather data in certain cities and I have a dropdown and based on the dropdown selection, an api should be called (based on city name), when I tap on a city for the first time the app runs it returns nil and if I tap on another city it returns data based on the first selection, I have debugged and traced the code line by line however the URL is correct and the everything seems to be in order, any help? here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempraturevalue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityname: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temprature: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var cityButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func handleSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cityButtons.forEach{ (button) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            
        }
    }
    enum Cities:String {
        case amman = "Amman"
        case azzerqa = "Az zerqa"
        case irbid = "Irbid"
        case aqaba = "Aqaba"
    }
    var tempraturevalueData:Double = 0.0
    var cityNameData:String = ""
    @IBAction func cityTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let title = sender.currentTitle, let City = Cities(rawValue: title)
            
            else {
            return
        }
        var city:String
        switch City {
        case .amman:
            city = "Amman"
        case .azzerqa:
                  city = "zerqa"
        case .irbid:
            city = "Irbid"
        case .aqaba:
            city = "Aqaba"
        }
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={key}&q=\(city)")
        guard url != nil else {
            print("error creating URL Object")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy , timeoutInterval: 10)
        let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:  {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                do {
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               
                    do {
                        let weatherdatadecoded = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data!)
                        self.tempraturevalueData = weatherdatadecoded.current?.temp_c ?? 0.1
                        self.cityNameData = weatherdatadecoded.location?.name ?? "no city found"
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
        print(self.cityNameData)
        print(self.tempraturevalueData)
    }

}
```

Comment: Move your prints inside `do` block.

Comment: @gcharita it worked thank you, however when I try to assign those values to the labels. text in the following code: 
self.cityname.text = self.cityNameData
self.tempraturevalue.text = String(self.tempraturevalueData)

I got an error error: "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: there is a purple notification mentioned that "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

Comment: You are closing in a solution as we speak. :) Try to run your code in main thread. There are plenty of articles on how to do that.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/